# connecting to an android phone in PC side

Tags: android, bluetooth, rfcomm

I am working on a project that a program in an android phone connects to a PC via Bluetooth and sends some commands.

Now my problem is connecting to an android phone with RFCOMM in PC side.
Any codes, samples, tutorials, libraries can help me so please share them.
Also it's better to be in a native language like C and Delphi not Java or .Net .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a specific language or details of the bluetooth stack or operating system you are using providing a detailed answer is impossible so this answer is necessarily vague.

Your android application is almost certainly using SPP (Serial Port Profile) over RFComm. If you configure your phone as the slave device the bluetooth stack on your PC should see it as a Com Port.

You talk to this port in the same way as any other serial port. just open a connection and send/receive characters).

The only complexity is that you will need to pair your phone with the PC using the normal configuration menus.

Comment: thanks for your answer I actually forgot, I want to Write the program for windows . what language do you suggest for Bluetooth programming?

Comment: I've mainly used c#.NET but that's only because I know it. If you use the comm port approach you should be able to use any language you are familiar with - both C and Delphi have support for serial ports. You can even use a terminal emulator program like PuTTY on the PC to test simple communications then code it in your language of choice.

Answer (score 2):

After some searches i found a nice library for java that is called bluecove. it works with rfcomm obex and so on and also it supports linux windows and mac. http://bluecove.org/

Now my project works. :-)